# Find duplicates put sequence for each one

Tags: excel, vba

Assume I have data in column (A) like the following:

Names
Yasser
Hany
Ahmed
Reda
Ahmed
Yasser
Reda
Yasser

Duplicates can be detected using such a code

```
Sub Find_Duplicates()
    Dim e, x(), dic As Object, cel As Range, lr As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
            For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & lr)
                If Not .Exists(cel.Value) Then
                    .Item(cel.Value) = cel.Value & "^" & cel.Address(0, 0)
                Else
                    .Item(cel.Value) = Split(.Item(cel.Value), "^")(0) & " | " & cel.Value & "^" & Split(.Item(cel.Value), "^")(1) & " | " & cel.Address(0, 0)
                End If
            Next cel
            If .Count Then
                ReDim x(1 To .Count, 1 To 2)
                For Each e In .Keys
                    If InStr(.Item(e), "|") > 0 Then
                        i = i + 1
                        x(i, 1) = Split(.Item(e), "^")(0)
                        x(i, 2) = Split(.Item(e), "^")(1)
                    End If
                Next e
            End If
            Columns("F:G").ClearContents
            Range("F1:G1").Value = Array("Duplicate Entries", "Address")
            If i > 0 Then Range("F2").Resize(i, 2).Value = x
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The output would be in columns F & G like that
[image]

What I am trying to get is like that (in Column B)

[image]

Comment: I don't see how the data in your column B gives you more information as you have in column A. Becaus actually all `Yasser` are converted to `Duplicate1`, all `Ahmed` are converted `Duplicate2` and so on. So actually you just replace names by other names. • Actually I think you asked X but your actual issue is Y (see [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Can you describe in your question what your actual goal is why you need to do that?

Comment: Will the ranges stay that way and will the list in columns F-G stay ordered in that way? Because in such case a formula should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your subroutine like this:

```vb
Sub Find_Duplicates()
    Dim e, x(), dic As Object, cel As Range, lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arr() As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & lr)
            If Not .Exists(cel.Value) Then
                .Item(cel.Value) = cel.Value & "^" & cel.Address(0, 0)
            Else
                .Item(cel.Value) = Split(.Item(cel.Value), "^")(0) & " | " & cel.Value & "^" & Split(.Item(cel.Value), "^")(1) & " | " & cel.Address(0, 0)
            End If
        Next cel
        If .Count Then
            ReDim x(1 To .Count, 1 To 2)
            For Each e In .Keys
                If InStr(.Item(e), "|") > 0 Then
                    i = i + 1
                    arr = Split(Split(.Item(e), "^")(1), "|")
                    
                    For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                        Set cel = Range(Trim(arr(j)))
                        Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column + 1).Value = "Duplicate" & CStr(i)
                    Next j
                End If
            Next e
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here, the cell addresses are split from each item and into an array of strings. Each cell address is used to move one cell to the right and then write the duplicate number there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the output is not as expected.

Comment: Yes, my mistake! You are correct. So the number means which duplicate. I've updated my answer to do this :)

Answer (score 3):

If you decide on formulas instead, then you could use:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$9,A2)>1,"Duplicate"&MATCH(A2,UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$9,COUNTIF(A$2:A$9,A$2:A$9)>1)),0),"")
```

Non-ExcelO365 users could use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$9,A2)>1,IF(MATCH(A2,A$1:A$9,0)=ROW(),"Duplicate"&MAX(IFERROR(--MID(B$1:B1,10,99),0))+1,INDEX(B$1:B1,MATCH(A2,A$1:A$9,0))),"")
```

Be sure to accept the formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Amazing solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide a code as some of the users that will use the code don't have office 365?

Comment: I wish I could select both the answers. I like your solution too, but as I said will not fit all the users.

Comment: @YasserKhalil, no worries. I added a non-O365 formula just in case.